# How to remove the comma in the last number?

Tags: c

The list must show this: "1,2,3,4"

but this code outputs: "1,,2,,,3,,,4".

What could be wrong in this code?

```c
for (i = 1; i <= num1; ++i) {
    if(num1 % i == 0)
        printf("%d",i);
    if(i<num1)
        printf(",");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Comma has to be printed only when you are printing a number, so put it in the same `if`.

```
for(i = 1; i <= num1; ++i) {
      if(num1 % i == 0){
          printf("%d",i);
          if(i<num1)
            printf(",");
      }
}
```

Comment: Please don't write a code-only answer. Explain the cause of the issue and how it should be resolved. We're not a debugging service.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are printing `,` even for numbers that don't pass the check

Fixed:

```c
for (i = 1; i <= num1; ++i) {
    if (num1 % i == 0) {
        printf("%d", i);
        if (i < num1)
            printf(",");
    }
}

printf("\n");
```

---

The above relies on the last element passing the check. Because that's the case, it can be simplified to the following:

```c
for (i = 1; i < num1; ++i) {
    if (num1 % i == 0) {
       printf("%d,", i);
    }
}

printf("%d\n", num1);
```

---

But, generally speaking, you can't rely on the last number passing the check. The following is a more general approach that doesn't rely on the last number passing the check:

```c
const char *prefix = "";
for (i = 1; i <= num1; ++i) {
    if (num1 % i == 0) {
       printf("%s%d", prefix, i);
       prefix = ",";
    }
}

printf("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Or more efficiently than above:

```
for (i = 1; i < num1; ++i) {
    if (num1 % i == 0) {
        printf("%d,",i);
    }
}
printf("%d",num1);
```

In other words:

1. No need to check `i < num1` at every iteration
2. No need to check `num1 % i == 0` at the last iteration

Answer (score 0):

To avoid `if` or the conditional operator (`?:`) I usually just print the first item outside the loop

```
printf("1");                       // 1
for (i = 2; i <= num1; ++i) {                             // note: start at 2
    if (num1 % i == 0) {
        printf(", %d", i);         // , 2, 3, 4, ..., n
    }
}
printf("\n");                      // newline
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's the really short version, using the ternary operator:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int num1=24;
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= num1; ++i)
        printf((num1%i)? "": "%d%s", i, (i<num1)? "," : "");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 5660KB
1,2,3,4,6,8,12,24
```

Comment: To the person who vandalized my answer, calling it the conditional operator.  No.  It is called the ternary operator (https://syntaxdb.com/ref/c/ternary#:~:text=The%20ternary%20operator%20is%20used,behaving%20similar%20to%20a%20function.)  An *alternate* name is the "ternary conditional" operator.  "Conditional operator" is a  short-hand slang term for it.

Comment: Just like your unreliable source, you are mistaken. It is called the [conditional operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator). It is *a* ternary operator, and it is C's *only* ternary operator, but its called the conditional operator. Calling it the ternary operator is like calling addition a binary operator.

Comment: Anyway, the point of the edit was to make the code more readable, because you had to scroll to see it. I just did that fix since I was already fixing problems with your answer. I wouldn't have changed it otherwise since it's widely called the ternary operator even though that's not its name. But fixing the error doesn't make vandalism.

Comment: Sorry, that link was for C++. [Correct link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator). And [from the actual C spec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9Bwd.png). (Well, a very late draft of it.)